# Yii2 adminlte 2 bower/adminlte/dist directory doesn't exist

Tags: yii2

I installed adminlte 2 on Yii2-advanced app by the instructions listed [here](https://github.com/annaselh/yii2adminlte). After finishing all the instruction what I get is `The file or directory to be published does not exist: C:\xampp\htdocs\fitness/vendor/bower/adminlte/dist`. From what I found around the google and especially - github, didn't fix the error. The `dist` directory is there. This is my backend folder `composer.json` :

```
{
    "require": {
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800,
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
}
```

The `config` part is what I found after little research but still didn't help me.
Can someone give me advice, how to fix this. I am trying from almost 5 hours.... 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: that is not a credible resource the actual used is this one https://github.com/dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset, try using the way described here

Comment: Where should I execute the composer command ? In the root directory or in `backend` ?

Comment: `composer.json` is in the root of the project directory not `frontend` or `backend` so run `composer update` or any other command from the root of the project.